# Limit decimal digits on field of a view created with SqlAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, view, sqlalchemy, format, numeric

Having created this view:

```
class OpenPositionMetric(Base):
    stmt = (
        select(
            [
                OpenPosition.belongs_to.label("belongs_to"),
                OpenPosition.account_number.label("account_number"),
                OpenPosition.exchange.label("exchange"),
                OpenPosition.symbol.label("symbol"),
                round(OpenPosition.actual_shares * OpenPosition.avg_cost_per_share,3).label(
                    "cost_value"
                ),
            ]
        )
        .select_from(OpenPosition)
        .order_by("belongs_to", "account_number", "exchange", "symbol")
    )

    view = create_materialized_view(
        name="vw_open_positions_metrics",
        selectable=stmt,
        metadata=Base.metadata,
        indexes=None,
    )
    __table__ = view
```

I get the example result for the field **cost_value**: 1067.2500060000000000.

Is there a way to limit the number of decimal digits for that view field?

The function round() doesn't work. Maybe because round is a python function and SqlAlchemy is expecting and sql expression language function like **func.sum**?

Update:

I've found a solution but it isn't pretty. I'm sure there is a better one...

```
(text("ROUND (operations.tb_open_positions.actual_shares * operations.tb_open_positions.avg_cost_per_share,3) AS cost_value"))),
```

The value above is now displayed in the view as **1067.250**

Comment: round(OpenPosition.actual_shares * OpenPosition.avg_cost_per_share, 3)? Where it would be rounded to 3 places.

Comment: it doesn´t work: TypeError: type BinaryExpression doesn't define __round__ method

Comment: Show the entire code of what you did  as an update to your question.

Comment: Updated with round() function.

Comment: Try: `(round(OpenPosition.actual_shares * OpenPosition.avg_cost_per_share, 3)).label("cost_value)`

Comment: Same error. I'll try using sql.expression.text for an alternate solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to limit the number of decimal places would be to cast the result to `Numeric`:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

# …

class OpenPosition(Base):
    __tablename__ = "open_position"
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    actual_shares = sa.Column(sa.Float)
    avg_cost_per_share = sa.Column(sa.Float)


Base.metadata.drop_all(engine, checkfirst=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with sa.orm.Session(engine, future=True) as session:
    session.add(
        OpenPosition(id=1, actual_shares=1, avg_cost_per_share=1067.250606)
    )
    session.commit()
    result = session.query(
        (OpenPosition.actual_shares * OpenPosition.avg_cost_per_share).label(
            "cost_value"
        )
    ).all()
    print(result)  # [(1067.250606,)]

    result = session.query(
        sa.cast(
            (
                OpenPosition.actual_shares * OpenPosition.avg_cost_per_share
            ).label("cost_value"),
            sa.Numeric(10, 3),
        )
    ).all()
    print(result)  # [(Decimal('1067.251'),)]
```

Comment: Thank you. It really works even while creating the view.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution** (thanks [Gord Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2144390/gord-thompson)) :

```
from sqlalchemy import cast, Numeric

class OpenPositionMetric(Base):
    stmt = (
        select(
            [
                OpenPosition.belongs_to.label("belongs_to"),
                OpenPosition.account_number.label("account_number"),
                OpenPosition.exchange.label("exchange"),
                OpenPosition.symbol.label("symbol"),
                (
                    cast(
                        OpenPosition.actual_shares * OpenPosition.avg_cost_per_share,
                        Numeric(10, 3),
                    )
                ).label("cost_value")

            ]
        )
        .select_from(OpenPosition)
        .order_by("belongs_to", "account_number", "exchange", "symbol")
    )

    view = create_materialized_view(
        name="vw_open_positions_metrics",
        selectable=stmt,
        metadata=Base.metadata,
        indexes=None,
    )
    __table__ = view
```